# Extend the Madison Store from code

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad, websphere-commerce

I am developing a plugin on websphere commerce allowing stores created from this platform can communicate with each. Using 'Accelerator', 'Administrator Console' and 'IBM Management Tools', I customized the Madison Store I created from these applications but I need to add code snippets, I don't know if I should use the IBM Rational Application Developer to do this, or if there is another way to edit the store created.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What worked and didn't work?  (I don't know anything about "Madison Store" or "Management Tools", but I don't think your question has enough detail to get a useful response.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you created the plugin, generally speaking you have to use Websphere Commerce Developer to do this.   It's needs the WebSphere Commerce specific libraries in order to compile the site.